# Specify KMS Key to encrypt data during datasink in AWS Glue Job

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-kms

I have a scala job that read table data and writes it to a s3 bucket in parquet format. I want to encrypt the data using KMS and place in s3 bucket. I know that ETL Job run has option to select server side encryption but that uses AES256 and has no option to select KMS. Is it possible to do this?

I have already tried the solution given for a different question but it didn't work.

[Similar question previously asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49405198/can-a-ssekms-key-id-be-specified-when-writing-to-s3-in-an-aws-glue-job)

Comment: Solution in the previous answer should work for server-side encryption. Did you get any error? Or files were not encrypted at the end? Also try to create GlueContext after setting encryption properties.

Comment: The files were not encrypted. And I also set the properties before GlueContext